# Delete records with select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to Delete all The Records which the is returned by following query:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM [Customer] C
    INNER JOIN [BillingStatus] BS 
    ON BS.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
    INNER JOIN [TCDetails] TC 
    ON TC.CustomerID = BS.CustomerID    
    INNER JOIN [BillingDetails] BD 
    ON BS.CustomerID = BD.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN [AgencyDetails] AD
    ON BD.CustomerID = AD.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN [CustomerDetails] CD
    ON CD.CustomerID = AD.CustomerID
    WHERE C.CYC = 27
```

Comment: You mean from all the tables?

Comment: Dont understand one thing whats the point in tagging the question with mysql,sql-server together ?

Comment: @TomasPastircak Yes from all the join tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to delete from all the tables, so it would probably be simpler to first declare the customer IDs to some temporary table:

```
SELECT CustomerID 
INTO #TempCustomer 
FROM Customer
WHERE CYC = 27
```

Then, you'll need to delete from each of these tables:

```
DELETE FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM #TempCustomer)
DELETE FROM BillingStatus WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM #TempCustomer)
DELETE FROM TCDetails WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM #TempCustomer)
DELETE FROM BillingDetails WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM #TempCustomer)
DELETE FROM AgencyDetails WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM #TempCustomer)
DELETE FROM CustomerDetails WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM #TempCustomer)
```

At the end, to clean up after you, you should drop the temporary table you created as well:

```
DROP TABLE #TempCustomer
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomas I want something like this.

Comment: @AbhishekSinghal I improved the answer now, I forgot to add the deletion from Customer table.

Comment: No Problem I also want to delete some more tables.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments you want to delete `Customer` and all it's relations in other tables so, first of all set `Cascade Delete` on foreign keys from `Customer` to other Tables, then `Delete` Customer with this query all other tables will be deleted

```
DELETE FROM [Customer] WHERE CYC = 27
```